# select range of rows from a table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table XYZ(ID Primary key,Name).The table is having more than 10000 rows.
I want to process 1000 rows at a time.For this i have to first 1000 rows from the table and then update the table as per the results.For the first 1000 rows i can fetch using

```
   select *  from XYZ where rownum >=1 and rownum <= 1000
```

but for the next 1000 rows i do not know how to write the query because if i write

```
select count(*)  from XYZ where rownum >=1000 and rownum < 2000
```

the query gives 0 rows.Any idea how to write the query.Please help.I am using Oracle 11g database.

Answer (score 3):

`rownum` isn't a real column, it's a pseudocolumn that is generated as rows are generated, starting at 1 and counting upward.

So, your query:
`select *  from XYZ where rownum >= 1000 and rownum <= 2000`

Returns no rows.  Why?  Oracle generates the first row and assigns it a rownum of 1.  It then checks to see if it should be included in the result set.  Rownum < 1000, so no.  It goes on to the next row, and uses the next largest not yet used rownum ... which is still 1.  Repeat until end of table.

You need to introduce a subselect to transform the `rownum` into a real column:

```
select * from
  (select rownum r, * from xyz) inner
where
  inner.r >= 1000 and inner.r <= 2000
```

To get the results you really want.

Comment: THANKS DONNIE FOR YOUR ANSWER.IF I USE THIS QUERY WILL IT BE OPTIMIZE.BECAUSE WE ARE FECTHING 10000 ROWS FIRST AND THEN SELECTING 1000 ROWS FROM THE RESULT.